# Information from index of center.

Tags: group-theory

Let G be the group. Z is center of group with $|G:Z|=9$.then i have to show that $\forall g\in G$ ,$g^3\in Z $  .

I know that if $G/Z(G)$ cyclic then abelian .But here I can only deduce that G/Z is abelian as any group of order $p^2$.I am not abel to deduce any thing further.

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Look at the quotient G/Z. As you said, if it's cyclic then G is abelian, which is contradiction with |G:Z|=9. What about the order of the elements in G/Z, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $G/Z(G)$ is an abelian group of order $p^2=3^2$. So it is either isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/3\times \Bbb{Z}/3$, or it is cyclic and isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/9$. In the second case we have $G=Z(G)$ as you said, which is a contradiction to $(G:Z(G))=9$.

A related result (but different): Suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $|G/N|= m$. Then we have $g^m\in N$ for all $g\in G$. The proof uses the order of elements in $G/N$.